# How to run a Flask (1.0.2) app on an OS-assigned port

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a Flask app to host a REST API service. In order to distribute the code for testing on differing systems, I can't hard-code the port that the application runs on.

When running Flask 0.12.2 I am able to use the command `app.run(port=0)` to get a usable port assigned by the OS. This works.

When I try the same command with Flask 1.0.2, I receive the message `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`.

Does anyone know why there is this discrepancy, and whether there's a workaround using Flask 1.0.2?

I'm aware that it's possible to get a socket assigned by the OS using Python's `socket` module, but the ensuing race condition isn't acceptable for the testing environment.

Comment: try to use a port other than 0. Try using 8888

Comment: Does 8888 have special properties? I can't hard-code the port, as stated in the question

Comment: Hard coding in a specific, available port does work. I can't make the assumption that any specific port will be free on all the machines this may run on though

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085656/how-to-get-the-current-port-number-in-flask

Comment: That generates the race condition mentioned in the question. That race condition is not acceptable in the testing environment

Comment: If the most important thing is for the app to start no matter the port, then you can randomize the port selection and try `app.run(port=<yournumber>)` until it goes through. This way you can handle clashes which apparently can happen in your environment. If there is another constraint, please explain.

Comment: I'll consider the randomized option. I would really like to find out why this feature of Flask seems to have regressed, but that may be a suitable work around.

Comment: I feel you. It might reside in changes in `werkzeug`, but haven't looked into it.